# jaxb - how to create XML from polymorphic classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, polymorphism

I've just started using JAXB to make XML output from java objects. A polymorphism exists in my java classes, which seems to not working in JAXB.

Below is the way how I tried to deal with it, but in the output I haven't expected field: fieldA or fieldB.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name = "fieldInRoot")
    private String fieldInRoot;
    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    private BodyResponse child;
    // + getters and setters
}

public abstract class BodyResponse {
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ResponseA")
public class ResponseA extends BodyResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "fieldA")
    String fieldB;
    // + getters and setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ResponseB")
public class ResponseB extends BodyResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "fieldB")
    String fieldB;  
    // + getters and setters  
}
```

Before I start invent some intricate inheritances, is there any good approach to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your use case you will probably want to leverage `@XmlElementRefs`, this corresponds to the concept of substitution groups in XML Schema:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElement
    private String fieldInRoot;
    @XmlElementRef
    private BodyResponse child;
    // + getters and setters
}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

You can also leverage the `xsi:type` attribute as the inheritance indicator:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) also has the `@XmlDescriminatorNode`/`@XmlDescriminatorValue` extension:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

Comment: yes, that works perfectly. Thanks for this post and reference to your blog.

Answer (score 2):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {
    ....

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type = ResponseA.class, name = "ResponseA"),
        @XmlElement(type = ResponseB.class, name = "ResponseB")})
    private BodyResponse child;

}
```

Maybe you need an `@XmlType(name = "ResponseX")` on your `Response` classes.

Comment: The `@XmlElements` mapping in JAXB exists to represent choice structures (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html).  For this inheritance use case the concept of substitution groups is a better fit and is mapped with `@XmlElementRefs` (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html).