# How to serialize polymorphic list with element type names as xml element names in Jackson

Tags: jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a list of objects with common base class. I wish to serialize (and deserialize) this list so that each list element is serialized with its root element equal to the name of the type and not have the wrapping object around the element.

I tried using JsonTypeInfo with Id.Name and As.WRAPPER_OBJECT which produces an XML with proper element names but (obviously) with another layer of XML elements (from the list itself).

```
package zm.study.xmlserialize.jackson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class JacksonListTest4 {

  public static class L {
    public List<A> as = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
  @JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=B.class, name="b"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=C.class, name="c"),
  })
  public static abstract class A {

  }

  public static class B extends A {

  }

  public static class C extends A {

  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception
  {
    L l = new L();
    l.as.add(new B());
    l.as.add(new C());

    new XmlMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
      .writeValue(System.out, l);

  }

}
```

I would like to get:

```
<L>
  <as>
      <b/>
      <c/>
  </as>
</L>
```

Instead I get:

```
<L>
  <as>
    <as>
      <b/>
    </as>
    <as>
      <c/>
    </as>
  </as>
</L>
```

Comment: Your should switch to another JAXB implentation until this bug is fixed: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/230  ( in JAXB this solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499735/jaxb-how-to-create-xml-from-polymorphic-classes )

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you want it to look like you're better off writing an [XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) and then using a tool like [JAXB](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to create a serialization/deserialization Java object.